# How to send with 'params.put' in Dart or Flutter JsonObjectLite

Tags: flutter, dart

1. In java it would be something like this ...

```
    public Request compose(LoginDevice login) {
              JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
              try {
                if (login.granType != null)
                  params.put("grant_type", login.granType); 
                if (login.clientId != null)
                  params.put("client_id", login.clientId);
              } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
              } 
              return (Request)new BaseRequest("oauth/v2/token", params.toString(), new HashSet());
            }
```

2. And in Dart and tried something similar but it doesn't work... the parameter 'put' does not exist in JsonObjectLite...

```
    Request compose(LoginDevice login)
        {
            JsonObjectLite params = new JsonObjectLite();
            try {
                if (login.granType != null) {
                    params.put("grant_type", login.granType);
                }
                if (login.clientId != null) {
                    params.put("client_id", login.clientId);
                }
            } on JsonObjectLiteException catch (e) {
                print(e);
            }
            return new BaseRequest("oauth/v2/token", params.toString(), new HashSet());
        }
```

How could I do it? Thank you

Comment: Do you are serializing the object in JSON right? Why you don't use the `dart:convert` or `json_serializable`?

Comment: The **json_serializable** is not very clear to me how to use it to be able to solve that part of my code since I am new to Flutter/Dart and the **dart:convert** I use it but for other things, for what I want it is not useful

Comment: I think the json_serializable worked how GSON, I can make an example for you, on this day.

Comment: Okay, i appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class `JsonObjectLite` doesn't contain the method put.

How you can understand dart doesn't is Java, in this cases your the class `JsonObjectLite` has a method called `putIfAbsent`, the implementation is the following

```
 /// If [isImmutable] is false, or the key already exists,
  /// then allow the edit.
  /// Throw [JsonObjectLiteException] if we're not allowed to add a new
  /// key
  @override
  void putIfAbsent(dynamic key, Function() ifAbsent) {
    if (isImmutable == false || containsKey(key)) {
      _objectData.putIfAbsent(key, ifAbsent);
    } else {
      throw const JsonObjectLiteException('JsonObject is not extendable');
    }
  }
```

look also the [Source code](https://github.com/shamblett/json_object_lite/blob/2422c42a0cf11bb760214f583609459f380536f7/lib/src/json_object_lite.dart#L342)

So an example of code should be the following

```
import 'package:json_object_lite/json_object_lite.dart';

class AuthorAnswer {
  var _username;
  var _status;

  AuthorAnswer(this._username, this._status);

  String get username => _username;

  String get status => _status;


}

int main() {

  var author = '@vincenzopalazzo';
  var sentences = 'Follow me on Github';

  var authorObject = AuthorAnswer(author, sentences);

  try{
    JsonObjectLite params = new JsonObjectLite();
    params.isImmutable = false;
    params.putIfAbsent("author", () => authorObject.username);
    params.putIfAbsent("sencence", () => authorObject.status);

    print(params.toString());
  } on JsonObjectLiteException catch (err){
    print('--------- ERROR ----------');
    print(err);
  }


  return 0;
}
```

You should be set the `params.isImmutable = false` and after you can add your propriety, with your logic.

In my opinion, I don't see any motivation to use this library, dart have 2 types of the module to implement the serialization, and I think should better use it because on the web exist the documentation, like this [dart json](https://dart.dev/guides/json), [flutter json](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json)

Inside the flutter app, there are also the line guides, for the small application you can use `dart:convert:json` also for the other you can use the `json_serializable`

I want to add also an example of `dart:convert`

```
/**
 * 
 */

import "dart:core";
import "dart:convert";


class ClassToJsonOne {

  var _propOne;
  var _propTwo;

  ClassToJsonOne(this._propOne, this._propTwo);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJSon() => {
    'prop_one': _propOne,
    'prop_two': _propTwo
  };

  ClassToJsonOne.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json): 
    _propOne = json['prop_one'],
    _propTwo = json['prop_two'];

  @override
  String toString() => 'First Class: $_propOne, $_propTwo';

}

class ClassToJsonTwo{

  var _propOne;
  var _propTwo;

  ClassToJsonTwo(this._propOne, this._propTwo);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJSon() => {
    'prop_one': _propOne,
    'prop_two': _propTwo
  };

  ClassToJsonTwo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json): 
    _propOne = json['prop_one'],
    _propTwo = json['prop_two'];

  @override
  String toString() => 'Second Class: $_propOne, $_propTwo';
}

main(List<String> args) {

  print('------- Declare Objecr -------\n');
  var objectToJsonOne = ClassToJsonOne('I am the fist object', 'empty');
  var objectToJsonTwo = ClassToJsonTwo('I contains the first object', 'empty');

  String jsonStringObjOne = jsonEncode(objectToJsonOne.toJSon());
  print('\n---------- Object one JSON format ---------\n');
  print(jsonStringObjOne);
  String jsonStringObjTwo = jsonEncode(objectToJsonTwo.toJSon());
  print('\n---------- Object one JSON format ---------\n');
  print(jsonStringObjTwo);

  print('\n---------- DECODE JSON to OBJECT ---------\n');
  var fromJsonObjectOne = jsonDecode(jsonStringObjOne);
  print(fromJsonObjectOne.toString());
  var fromJsonObjectTwo = jsonDecode(jsonStringObjTwo);
  print(fromJsonObjectTwo.toString());
}
```

Inside the classes, you can see the following methods

```
 Map<String, dynamic> toJSon() => {
    'prop_one': _propOne,
    'prop_two': _propTwo
  };

  ClassToJsonTwo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json): 
    _propOne = json['prop_one'],
    _propTwo = json['prop_two'];
```

The result of the method `toJSon`, you should be pass to the method of the library `jsonEncode` and when you go to deserialize you can use the library method `jsonDecode(youtStringJSOn)` and the result you can pass to the method of your class `fromJson`.

In addition, you can configure the library [json_serializable](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json#manual-encoding).

In conclusion, I want to fix my comment

> I think the json_serializable worked how GSON, I can make an example for you, on this day.

On flutter, documentation has reported this text

> Is there a GSON/Jackson/Moshi equivalent in Flutter?
>   The simple answer is no.
>
> Such a library would require using runtime reflection, which is disabled in Flutter. Runtime reflection interferes with tree shaking, which Dart has supported for quite a long time. With tree shaking, you can “shake off” unused code from your release builds. This optimizes the app’s size significantly.
>
> Since reflection makes all code implicitly used by default, it makes tree shaking difficult. The tools cannot know what parts are unused at runtime, so the redundant code is hard to strip away. App sizes cannot be easily optimized when using reflection.
>
> Although you cannot use runtime reflection with Flutter, some libraries give you similarly easy-to-use APIs but are based on code generation instead. This approach is covered in more detail in the code generation libraries section.

you can found the source code inside this answer [here](https://github.com/vincenzopalazzo/MyAnswerOnStackOverflow)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I have been able to solve it!!